# Color matching but print other lines too

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have an alias: `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`. I wish to have some way to print not only matching row but all of them and just color matching patterns. I doubt is there an option to do that in the `grep` itself. Any other tool ? Or idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: looks that your're right and this is a duplicate but I believe answers here are better same as the question - it's sharper without long, boring and unclear example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the trick with `-E` option:

```
grep -E '(^|pattern)' file
```

Here is a simple output:

[image]

Comment: Oooh, nice one!

Comment: Sneaky, +1! You can do it without `-E` also: `grep '^\|grep' cat`

Comment: `function ggrep() { grep --color=auto -E "(^|$@)"; }` and now it can be used that way: `echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz"|ggrep bar`

Comment: @terdon: Good point. use `-E` is only my habits.

Comment: @Gnouc, good habit given that `grep '\|'` is not standard/portable.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Yeap, so I always use `-E`

Comment: Why the parentheses though? `grep` colours the matched string, not capture groups.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: I just want to make it clearly for the OP. I think look at `^|pattern` can make it more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this using a bit `sed` and terminal magic:

```
$ sed -e 's/<pattern>/\x1b[31;01m&\x1b[m/g' <file>
```

This replaces each occurrence of `<pattern>` with the matched text surrounded by `\x1b[31;01m` (which is the terminal escape sequence for "set foreground color to bold red") and `\x1b[m` (same for "set foreground color to default").

Answer (score 3):

I've written a little script that will color whatever string you give it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Getopt::Std;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor; 

my %opts;
getopts('hic:l:',\%opts);
    if ($opts{h}){
      print<<EoF; 
Use -l to specify the pattern(s) to highlight. To specify more than one 
pattern use commas. 

-l : A Perl regular expression to be colored. Multiple expressions can be
     passed as comma separated values: -l foo,bar,baz
-i : makes the search case sensitive
-c : comma separated list of colors;

EoF
      exit(0);
    }

my $case_sensitive=$opts{i}||undef;
my @color=('bold red','bold blue', 'bold yellow', 'bold green', 
           'bold magenta', 'bold cyan', 'yellow on_magenta', 
           'bright_white on_red', 'bright_yellow on_red', 'white on_black');
if ($opts{c}) {
   @color=split(/,/,$opts{c});
}
my @patterns;
if($opts{l}){
     @patterns=split(/,/,$opts{l});
}
else{
    $patterns[0]='\*';
}

# Setting $| to non-zero forces a flush right away and after 
# every write or print on the currently selected output channel. 
$|=1;

while (my $line=<>) 
{ 
    for (my $c=0; $c<=$#patterns; $c++){
    if($case_sensitive){
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/){
           $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ge;
        }
    }
    else{
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/i){
          $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ige;
        }
      }
    }
    print STDOUT $line;
}
```

If you save it as `color` in a directory that is in your `$PATH` and make it executable (`chmod +x /usr/bin/color`), you can color the matched pattern like this:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nbib" | color -l foo,bib
```

That will produce:

[image]

As written, the script has predefined colors for 10 different patterns, so giving it a comma separated list as I have in the example above will color each of the patterns matched in a different color.

Comment: Nice one - you should share it through the Github

Comment: @pawel7318 I'm sharing it here :) I also have it on github actually: https://github.com/terdon/scripts/blob/master/color

Answer (score 3):

This is built into [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) -- colored output is the default, and the `--passthru` option prints all lines.